# receive a segmentation error when printing out words of array

Tags: c

The following is a piece of code where the user enters unknown amounts of words until `'E'` is entered, whereupon the program should stop and print out all of the entered words. However, when run this program produces a segmentation error. Did I access some memory I shouldn't have?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CAPACITY 10
#define NUM_OF_WORDS 10
int main(void)
{
    int num_words = 10;
    char *word= malloc(CAPACITY*sizeof(char));
    char **w=(char **) malloc(num_words*sizeof(char));
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; scanf("%s", word)==1; ++i)
    {
        if(*word == 'E') 
            break;
        if( i == num_words-1)
            w = (char **)realloc(w, (num_words *=2) * sizeof(char));
        w[i] =(char *) malloc(strlen(word)+1 * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(w[i], word);
    }
    int x = 0;
    for(x = 0 ; x<num_words ; x++)
        printf("%s", w[x]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What input makes it crash, and on what line?

Comment: @JohnZwinck is right.  "I received a segmentation error" is not very helpful without knowing how you tested it?  Does it crash immediately?  After certain input?  Have you run it in a debugger?

Comment: When i stopped from entering data and which the program supposed to print things out, i received i seg. error

Comment: in the `printf` `for` loop you should be going to i as that is the number of elements in the `w` array. This isn't the issue with the segFault @JonathanLeffler's answer fixes the segFault. Also you might want to change the `printf` format because as it is it will print all the elements next to each other without a space or newline between them.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial allocation code reads:

```
char *word = malloc(CAPACITY*sizeof(char));
char **w = (char **) malloc(num_words*sizeof(char));
```

Both these allocate 10 bytes of memory.  Your second one should read:

```
char **w = (char **) malloc(num_words*sizeof(char *));
```

or:

```
char **w = malloc(num_words*sizeof(*w));
```

These both allocate enough memory for 10 pointers (which might be eight times as much memory as your original code).  The second is arguably better style; the first is indubitably the classic style.  In C, the cast on `malloc()` is not necessary; in C++, it is.

This may not be the whole problem; it is almost certainly a contributory factor.

Also, you aren't checking your memory allocations; that is not advisable.  You should always check them.

---

This code:

```
if (i == num_words-1)
    w = (char **)realloc(w, (num_words *=2) * sizeof(char));
```

is playing with fire on two accounts (plus a repeat of the previously diagnosed problem):

1. The assignment within the argument list is...not generally reckoned to be a good idea.  I wouldn't write code with that in place, and I'd send back code I was asked to review that contained it.  It isn't technically wrong; it will work.  But it does not make life easier for the maintenance programmers who come after.
2. You should never reallocate a pointer such as `w` and assign the new space to the same pointer.  If the memory allocation fails, you'll get back a null pointer, so you've lost the only pointer to the previous data, which is still allocated.  That's a memory leak.  Also, if the memory allocation fails, you have to undo the assignment within the argument list because the allocated space is still at the original size.  I think you'd be better off using:

   ```
   if (i == num_words - 1)
   {
       size_t new_size = (num_words * 2);
       char **new_data = realloc(w, new_size * sizeof(*new_data));
       if (new_data == 0)
           ...handle error; w is still valid, and num_words is still correct too...
       num_words = new_size;
       w = new_data;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `num_words` holds the current maximum size of the `w` array, but that isn't the same as the number of words actually in the array.

When you loop through the `w` array you are looping through too many items - some elements of the `w` do not have a valid string in them - trying to print them will cause a segfault.

Comment: Yes, i think that is the problem as well, so its there any better solution to print them out?

Comment: @twain249 - it may or may not cause a segfault depending on what is in the malloc'd buffer.  malloc doesn't guarantee that the memory will be zeroed.